# Apply UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout on specific Collection View in View Controller with multiple Collection Views

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am designing a screen where I have 3 Collectio Views.

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var sizesCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

I wanna apply some methods of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout on just imgCollectionView.

```
extension ItemDetailVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        if collectionView == imgCollectionView{
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if collectionView == imgCollectionView{
            let size = collectionView.frame.size
            return CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height)
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if collectionView == imgCollectionView{
            return 0.0
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if collectionView == imgCollectionView{
            return 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

but I am having the errors for the missing return value.

[image]

Comment: you should return some value after the `if` statement because these are returning functions. simply add returning values after `if` statements for other collectionView's

Comment: I wanna apply these functions only for specific collection view

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom `UICollectionView` to do this

---

- Create custom `CollectionView`

```swift
public class ImageCollectionView: UICollectionView {

  override public func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.delegate = self
  }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension ImageCollectionView: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = collectionView.frame.size
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.0
    }
}
```

---

- Set your custom `CollectionView` in your `ItemDetailVC`

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var imgCollectionView: ImageCollectionView!
```

**NOTE:** You don't need to set `imgCollectionView.delegate` in `ItemDetailVC`

---

- Remove `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` functions from `ItemDetailVC`